# Calculate total number of values per day with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

**I have the following data frame**

```
       UNIT  C/A   DATETIME                TOTAL COUNTs
       R248  HOO7  2018-03-03 03:00:00     139.0
                   2018-03-03 07:00:00     927.0
                   2018-03-04 11:00:00    1946.0
                   2018-03-05 07:00:00    1330.0
                   2018-03-05 11:00:00    2358.0
```

I want to calculate the sum of 'TOTAL COUNTS' for each day.So I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
        UNIT  C/A   DATETIME     TOTAL COUNTs
       R248  HOO7  2018-03-03    1066
                   2018-03-04    1946
                   2018-03-05    3688
```

I read the I have to set the index of this dataframe to 'datetime' index and then use .resample, but I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use if 3 levels `MultiIndex` use [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
dates = df.index.get_level_values('DATETIME').floor('D')
```

Or:

```
dates = pd.Series(df.index.get_level_values('DATETIME').date, name='DATETIME', index=df.index)
```

If column `DATETIME`:

```
dates = df['DATETIME'.dt.floor('D')
dates = df['DATETIME'].dt.date
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['UNIT','C/A', dates]).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   UNIT   C/A   DATETIME  TOTAL COUNTs
0  R248  HOO7 2018-03-03        1066.0
1  R248  HOO7 2018-03-04        1946.0
2  R248  HOO7 2018-03-05        3688.0
```

Solution with `resample`:

```
df = df.set_index('DATETIME').groupby(['UNIT','C/A']).resample('D').sum().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df = df.groupby(['UNIT','C/A', pd.Grouper(key='DATETIME', freq='D')]).sum().reset_index()

print (df)
   UNIT   C/A   DATETIME  TOTAL COUNTs
0  R248  HOO7 2018-03-03        1066.0
1  R248  HOO7 2018-03-04        1946.0
2  R248  HOO7 2018-03-05        3688.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(df.DATETIME.dt.date)["TOTAL COUNTs"].sum()
```